# Dragging images inside of rich text editor

Tags: richtext, redactor

On [Redactor's website](http://imperavi.com/redactor/), they provide a demo with an image that you can click on and drag around the editor to relocate it among the text.

[Video example from Redactor's website](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223/Redactor_Website.mp4)

Trying this same functionality in the rich text editor in the Craft control panel doesn't work though. I even copied the demo HTML from Redactor's website and pasted it into Craft, without any luck.

[Video example from Craft control panel](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223/Craft_Website.mp4)

Has anybody been able to get this working or have any idea why this functionality would be missing in Craft?

Comment: It works for me, are there any javascript errors that show up for you when you load the page or try and move the image around?

Comment: Since this is a bug and will be fixed in an upcoming version of Craft (per [Brandon's comment below](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1383/45)), this thread will be closed as a bug report (aka "off-topic").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just looked into this and it’s a Craft bug. If you add an image manually using the “Insert URL” option, the image can be dragged around, but not if you use the “Choose image” option, which opens Craft’s image selection modal.

Saving the entry and coming back to it (or just typing Command + S) will also make the image draggable, regardless of how you added it.

We’ll get this fixed.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely (this would have to be confirmed by Pixel & Tonic), they didn't include the server-side scripting for handling that. Uploads in Craft are handled using Assets, which treats files as a whole lot more than just files. Allowing files to be dropped in would possibly be difficult with the kinds of options users have for handling files.

What you can do is click the image icon and select "Choose Image", you will get a modal pop up that does allow you to drag and drop in images. Afterwards, you'll be able to drag it around for placement. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it's an option.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually not looking to do any server side uploading of images, just moving existing images around inside of the editor. This should be fully controlled client side, but isn’t working in Craft. I updated my question with some example videos to make it clearer.